# When does the UINavigationBar shadow show? (iOS 6)

Tags: ios6, uinavigationbar

I am using a navigation bar with a custom background image. When I wanted to add a custom shadow image, I was surprised to find that even the default shadow image is not visible.

iOS 6 introduced an automatic drop shadow on UINavigationBars, which I expected to see. The example project from http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6 demonstrates this.

However, creating a new project from Xcode’s Master-Detail template does not show the shadow.

When exactly is the shadow shown, and when is it not?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ? I faced the same problem.

Comment: In Xcode 4.5 I continue to have this problem.

Comment: I'm having kind of the same problem. Shown in some VCs, not on some others. Notably those I created a while ago (maybe with Xcode 4.5) aren't shown. Any Idea? I can't recreate them, and it sounds nuts to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround, which I found half a year later, is actually embarrassingly simple:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

This said, I still believe this is a bug with how Xcode 4.4/4.5 configures navigation bars in storyboards. But at least now we know how to work around it. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

IOS 6 automatic drop shadow is shown by default. If you want to disable/hide this shadow you can try this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

What I have noticed is that, if I copy/paste a viewController from one project to a new one, the UINavigationBar shadow (sometimes) it's not shown. Replacing the copied viewController with a new one solves the problem... (maybe your case)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a project upgraded from iOS5, but only on navigation controllers inserted in the pre-iOS6 Xcode versions. Removing them and replacing them with new ones in the most recent version of Xcode (4.6) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Yang's answer, you can create a category to have a global fix like this

```
@interface UINavigationBar (JTDropShadowFix)

@end

@implementation UINavigationBar (JTDropShadowFix)

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.clipsToBounds = NO;
}

@end
```

If you're looking for a solution without hacking around with the category methods, you can also get to a blog post that talks about how to use a UINavigationController subclass to achieve the same fix.

http://ioscodesnippet.com/post/61487770156/custom-shadow-image-on-navigation-bar-ios6-fix

Answer (score 0):

to add some context: i just took my 1-year-old app [Cocktailicious](http://www.cocktailiciousapp.com/) and embedded the root `UINavigationView` in a `UITabBarController`. after that the old `UINavigationBar` had the property *Clip Subviews* checked in interface builder.

in the embedding process i also added a second navigation controller for a new tab in the tab bar. surprisingly, this controller came with *Clip Subviews* unchecked. feels like an xcode issue.